# jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

Tags: java, android, excel, xlsx

I want to open an Excel file in my Android application. I have copied the file to asset folder `(asset/Referance/myfile_db.xlsx)`. While creating the Workbook I am getting an error `jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream`. Here is my code,

```
       try{
             InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("Referance/myfile_db.xlsx");
            if(is!=null){
                Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(is); //Here am getting the Error
                Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, j);
                    System.out.println("Col "+j+": "+cell.getContents().toString());
                    if(cell.getContents().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Charger Rating Volts")){
                        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
                            Cell cel = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                            System.out.println("Col "+j+": "+cel.getContents().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error On Reading Excel : "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This library does not support .xlsx file format on import.